# No puedo retornar una vista en .net core mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

actualmente estoy trabajando en .net core mvc. Estoy utilizando el metodo  **ValidarTokenAjax** del controlador y luego retornar una vista que esta en el metodo **Pagar**, pero cuando lo ejecuto no importa que coloque en el return siempre el metodo **index** del controlador:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> ValidarTokenAjax(string tokenUser, string cedula)
    {

        TokenRequest objToken = new TokenRequest();

        var respuesta = objToken.ValidarToken(tokenUser, cedula);        

        return View("Pagar");

    }


 public async Task<IActionResult> Pagar()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: ¿Tu problema es que cuando lo ejecutas el explorador se abre en el `index`?

Comment: Prueba usar return RedirectToAction("Pagar");